# how to make a simple query that matches column values to a look-up then matches further columns if no match is found

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a simplified version of a problem I have.  Say I’ve got three variables all of the same type, in three columns of table1, and an id field.  They are all codes.  Mostly they map to variables (group identifyers say) contained in a look up in table2.  I want to write a query that does the following:

For each of my records I want to return the variable in table2 that my matches the code in the first of the three columns in table1.  However, if the variable in this column contains a value that does not have a match in table2, I want to try for a match using column2.  If that one does not match, use the one in column3.

I want the query result to contain the ID from table1 and the match from table2. If there is no match at all, then I want the query to contain a row with the id and n/a.

In this example there are just two values that match in my lookup.  I'm actually mapping across 12 columns with a few hundreds of unique code values and several million rows of data.

Table1

```
id  col1    col2    col3
1   V21 G22 T21
2   E30 W21 S34
3   Y11 U29 Q66
```

Table2

```
cat_code    class_group
V21 group1
W21 group2
```

Query result

```
id  class_group
1   group1
2   group2
3   n/a
```

So here in the desired result the record id 1 gets to match the very first column, and returns the corresponding variable, the second record can't get a match on the first but finds one on the second column and the third records can't match any value in any of the three columns so it throws an n/a.

I'm fairly new to SQL - I'm not sure whether this can be achieved in a simple query or whether it needs a functon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.id, 
    coalesce(t21.class_group, t22.class_group, t23.class_group) class_group
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t21 on t21.cat_code = t1.col1
left join Table2 t22 on t22.cat_code = t1.col2
left join Table2 t23 on t23.cat_code = t1.col3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on some test data. Thanks for the response. Coalesce looks really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Joel wrote... but he's quicker than I am :)

```
SELECT [Id], COALESCE(C1.[class_group], C2.[class_group], C2.[class_group], 'N/A')
FROM Table1 AS T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 AS C1 ON C1.[cat_code] = T1.[col1]
  LEFT JOIN Table2 AS C2 ON C2.[cat_code] = T1.[col2]
  LEFT JOIN Table2 AS C3 ON C3.[cat_code] = T1.[col3]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffb01/3

Comment: This throws an error(converting data type varchar to float).  Something to do with how it handles the N?A? But I followed the logic as per Joel's answer. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.class_group
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.cat_code
UNION
SELECT table1.id, table2.class_group
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col2 = table2.cat_code
SELECT table1.id, table2.class_group
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col3 = table2.cat_code
```

Comment: This works in that I get an output that correctly matches the data items that need matching but the query answer is split across two panes. Being an SQL newbie, I'm not sure why this is or how it would affect the useability of the output once I exported it. Thanks for the response.